# How do I get a REPL in bash?

Tags: bash

I am learning bash and would think it would make things easier if i didnt have to keep saving a file, switching terminals and then executing that file.  Is there a REPL in bash, sort of like irb for Ruby?

Comment: Isn't bash already kind of a repl? Have you seen this? https://github.com/erichs/composure

Comment: Hit `echo $0` in your console. If it answer *bash*, you're already into.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/erichs/composure and https://repl.it/languages

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure your login shell is `bash`. Open a terminal window. There, you have a `bash` REPL.

If your login shell is something else, open a terminal window and type `bash`.

Comment: It isn't technically a REPL because it doesn't *print* the result of the command it runs (which is its exit code) by default. (You can get this information in the prompt if you like -- just add `$?` to your prompt -- but a shell isn't strictly speaking a REPL.)

Comment: There is probably no reason to restrict it to a login shell.  Doing `/usr/bin/env bash` should work, or doing `bash` if `bash` is in your path should work.  No need to change `/etc/pwd` file or wherever it is set on your operating system for your login shell.